# Hair particle editing not working right

Tags: particles, edit-mode, hair

I am trying to brush hair on a character and suddenly the hair brush and other tools in particle edit have started affecting hairs on the opposite side of the mesh. This means whenever i make an edit on one side, hairs on the other side are affected. To be clear, this is **not** X-mirror, it is acting as if the source mesh is invisible. I am affecting hairs "through" the mesh.
Im probably just missing something, perhaps I hit a keyboard shortcut by accident while working.

Comment: Have you activated X-ray?

Comment: @rjg no, xray is disabled. it behaves the same regardless of xray mode anyway :(

Comment: @rjg I just discovered the bug was because I was using an experimental version of blender, its not present in the current stable release. I will just use the experimental version for rendering because of the new denoiser, and do all main work in the stable release. Lesson learned lol