# Disable backface particle editing (e.g. hair on other side of head)

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to use particle edit tools to edit hair on my character. Except it keeps editing the backface of the head. I've got x-ray turned off, tried viewport backface culling but nothing fixed this. Fyi, the scalp is a duplicated part of the head mesh.

[image]

This question is pretty much the same as this one except the only "answer" to that question involved a "bug" that was "solved":
[Hair particle editing not working right](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149484/hair-particle-editing-not-working-right)